Recover a complete file from an undo file and a backup copy
I use vim with auto backups and persistent undo. I just lost a file, and I want to recover as much of it as possible.
The backup contains most of the lost file, but the most recent changes are missing. However, those changes are in the undo file (I manually inspected the file, most of it is not human readable, but since it is a text document, I am fairly certain that the changes I made and need to recover are indeed in there, because there are fragments of the edited text I can read). In theory, between the backup file and the undo file, I should have all the information needed, but I don't know how to restore it.
I tried opening the backup file and manually loading the undo file (:rundo /path/to/undo/file), but it does not load, because "file contents changed, cannot use undo info". Is there a way to inspect the undo file without the original or something like that that would allow me to recover the lost progress?

no, not possible

It might be a good time to learn about version control :)
